# MariaDB single user account for simultaneous queries possible?

Tags: mariadb

Im developing a database application using MariaDB where I have a table for clients **registers**. I want them to be able to query the database, but I don't know if I have to create a database **user account** for each one in order to allow **simultanious** connections without collitions(same user trying to query at the same time) or can I use the same user account for **simultanieous** queries.

I'm kind of new to MariaDB.
Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are good at handling 'simultaneous' accesses by multiple connections to the same table.

The question of "one" versus "many" user accounts is independent of simultaneous access.

Most accesses work just fine without any problem.  In the extreme, I suggest you read about "deadlocks".